# Symfony 2.6.6 debug toolbar is not showing AJAX requests

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

After I've updated my **symfony2** dependencies via **Composer**, debug toolbar stopped showing AJAX requests. I see them in browser `Network` tab, but toolbar counter remains silent.

In `composer.json` symfony dependency declared as follows:

```
"require": {
    //...
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    //...
}
```

I think this issue is quite rare, and I've tried all the basic stuff - cache clear, etc. Maybe anyone encountered similar issue?

Comment: This is a known bug and has already been fixed in 2.6-dev: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14170 It'll be included in the next bug fix release of 2.6

Comment: Wow. Googled all around, but haven't seen this though. Thank you! Is it reasonable for you to post this as an answer, or we should just close the question?

Comment: I wasn't sure what's the best decision, so I've added a community wiki answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug and has already been fixed in 2.6-dev: http://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14170

It'll be included in the next bug fix release of 2.6